# Cannot run program "ping": CreateProcess error=8

Tags: java, memory, ping

In my java code, I use the `new ProcessBuilder("ping",  strIP);` in the start time, it runs normally, but after 24 hours, it will crash, showing that

> Cannot run program "ping": CreateProcess error=8  There is
>   insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. 
>   Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for
>   ChunkPool :allocate

I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please indicate what you have already researched.

Comment: Are you running out of stream buffer? Do you properly handle the ErrorStream and InputStream of your process?

Answer (score 1):

Ping process never stop if you don't kill the process.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("ping",  strIP);
Process process = pb.start(); //this will keep running and probably why you get insufficient memory after a long time
... //do whatever you need
process.destroy();  //stop the ping process
```

Comment: Nice catch. Using `-n` might be a preferable option, though.

Answer (score 0):

You have a memory leak in your code.  Post your code here.  Use JVisualVM to watch your heap grow until this exception is hit.  You can use [JVisualVM to find your leak](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8n7Bg7-A4I) too.

Answer (score 0):

evanwong is right.
Just to add another option, you could send an argument to the ping command, so it sends only X requests.

```
new ProcessBuilder("ping", "-c", pingRequestsNumber, strIP);
```

I feel like evanwong's way will send an unknown amount of requests until you stop it (which may be a better solution for your problem), but my way keeps under control the used resources.

I would probably use my method. If needed, I would launch the ping process multiple times, but I would be sure that I won't run out of memory, I don't stress out the server which receives the ping, it would be easier for me to read the server's log,...